# Слайдер как компонент или инфоблок для вставки на любую страницу мышкой (Битрикс)

Tags: php, битрикс, слайдер

Я хочу сделать слайдер/карусель как компонент или инфоблок для вставки на любую страницу. Чтобы не прописывать каждый раз код. А просто в визуальном редакторе на любой странице вставлять блок перетаскиванием мышкой. Ну и чтобы картинки задавать как прикрепленные.

Как это лучше сделать? Компонентом или инфоблоком? И как сделать чтобы просто в визуальном редакторе на любой странице вставлять блок перетаскиванием мышкой?

Где об этом можно почитать?

--

У меня есть готовый слайдер на главной странице, вставляется он вот так, во включаемую область `include/slider.php`, прописанную в коде главного шаблона сайта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В эту включаемую область я уже могу в визуальном редакторе добавлять блок слайдера мышкой (реализован инфоблоком как список новостей ).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как сделать так, чтобы не приходилось каждый раз прописывать код `include/slider.php` в **php** файлы, туда, где я хочу вставить слайдер, а просто добавлять мышкой на любую страницу?

Я например могу добавить блок мышкой вот так (через верхнее меню) на вот эту страницу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

перетягиванием из списка компонентов справа (по факту видно, что редактируется общая страница раздела а не конкретно текущая страница):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате получаю (это список новостей без заданного параметра шаблона, поэтому не выглядит как слайдер, но это не важно, не обращайте внимания):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но тогда этот блок появляется и на других страницах этого раздела тоже, что не нужно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же я пытаюсь добавить блок на эту страницу вот таким образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То я не могу этого сделать, т.к. нет компонентов в списке справа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=04790&LESSON_PATH=3913.3516.4790